# -[__NSDictionaryM objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutabledictionary

I searched for all possible combinations and answers on SO, but didn't helped me a lot.
All are related to `UITableView` only.

What I am doing is I am fetching my Quiz from server.
Quiz contain Sections and each section contain Questions.
So flow is like this.
Quiz->Section->Question

I am getting JSON like 
first total number of Quiz,
then total number of sections in particular Quiz
and total number of Questions in particular section.

I am storing Sections in sections array and parsing questions according to section array count.
but My app is crashing at point, where I am getting object of Question from section array and storing it in `NSMutableDictionary` with key to get connected with DTO.

Here is my code..

```
NSArray *sectionsA = [quizD objectForKey:@"sections"];
NSMutableArray *sectionDTOA = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray* questionDTOA=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i =0; i<[sectionsA count]; i++)
{
NSMutableDictionary* sectionD = [sectionsA objectAtIndex:i];
SectionDTO* sectionDTO = [[SectionDTO alloc]init];
[sectionDTO setSection_id:[sectionD objectForKey:@"sectionID"]];
[sectionDTO setSection_name:[sectionD objectForKey:@"sectionDTitle"]];
[sectionDTO setSection_description:[sectionD objectForKey:@"sectionDDesc"]];
[sectionDTO setSectionCutoff:[sectionD objectForKey:@"sectionCutoff"]];
```

// code for setting Questions goes below and after that for loop closed..

my app is crashing at line

```
NSMutableDictionary* sectionD = [sectionsA objectAtIndex:i];
```

Saying that

```
-[__NSDictionaryM objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Whats is wrong in my code,
I tried by getting array and then key value pair, but didn't helped.
Please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray *sectionsA = [quizD objectForKey:@"sections"];
```

the return value should be a `NSDictionary`, not `NSArray`.

Following demo code maybe help you:

```
NSArray *sectionsA = nil;  
id sectionsObj = [quizD objectForKey:@"sections"];
if([sectionsObj isKindOfClass:[Dictionary class]]){
     sectionsA = sectionsObj[@"keyForArray"];  //@"keyForArray" is the key for array
}
else if([sectionsObj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
    sectionsA = sectionsObj;
}
```